# Decrypt OpenPGP Session Key

Tags: cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle, gnupg, openpgp

I have a file encrypted using GPG that I would like to extract the session key from so I can decrypt the session key separately. I'm using Bouncy Castle to extract the session key using the following code:

```
private static void outputSessionKey(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BCPGInputStream input = new BCPGInputStream(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(new FileInputStream(path)));
    Packet packet;
    while((packet = input.readPacket()) != null) {
        if (packet instanceof PublicKeyEncSessionPacket) {
            PublicKeyEncSessionPacket encPacket = (PublicKeyEncSessionPacket) packet;
            byte[] encKey = encPacket.getEncSessionKey()[0];
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("session_key_enc.bin");
            output.write(encKey);
            output.close();
         }
     }

    input.close();
}
```

I then decrypt the session key using the following OpenSSL command:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -in session_key_enc.bin -out session_key_dec.bin -inkey private.pem -raw
```

I would expect the raw output to now be the decrypted session key but I am unable to use it to decrypt the original file using --override-session-key.

Does anyone have an idea about what could be going wrong with this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things (at least) that *should* go wrong.

(0) You are clearly assuming the key (and algorithm) used is RSA, which is not the only encryption algorithm used by PGP and GPG.

(1) The element(s) of `PublicKeyEncSessionPacket.getEncSessionKey()` is(are) the results of `MPInteger.getEncoded()` i.e. the MPI encoding from [rfc4880 sec 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.2) which is a two-octet bit length followed by the actual value octets. This value when written should be too large for RSA decryption and `rsautl -decrypt` should have given an error, at least assuming you are using the correct key.

(2) PGP's RSA encryption uses PKCS1-v1_5 (type 02) padding. After correcting (1) you need to use the default `-pkcs` not `-raw`.

With those changes it works for me. Note the RSA-encrypted key block 'm', as per [sec 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.1) consists of 1 octet symmetric-algorithm, the actual key, and 2 octets checksum; the first two are separated by a colon and the third is not included in GPG's session-key.

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for your answer. To address your points: 0. I'm not assuming that GPG is using RSA because that's what I've set the default to. 1. I didn't mention this in my post, but I did take off the first two bytes to isolate the bytes of the encrypted key. 2. I'll try your suggestion and see if it works. I was able to extract the decrypted key from the raw bytes but it seems like there are small discrepancies